# Seperate duplicate in string into list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a following string

```
"TAUXXTAUXXTAUXX"
```

i want to make a list contains the following

```
lst = ["TAUXX", "TAUXX", "TAUXX"]
```

How i make it and is there is a string library in python to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S : I want it in python

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to convert the string to a set and remove duplicates but it not work with string like TAUXX cause it have two X's and with set it will be TAUX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the string in its double:

```
s = 'TAUXXTAUXXTAUXX'

i = (s * 2).find(s, 1)
lst = len(s) // i * [s[:i]]

print(lst)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v1jBVkE9xDE0IgJBqHNxZQKFNYoVtBSMNPXSMvNSNIp1FAw1uXKKS4ASOal5GsWaCvr6CplAFdHF0VaZsbFcXAVFmXklGkAlmv//AwA)):

```
['TAUXX', 'TAUXX', 'TAUXX']
```

Comment: s+s[:-1] would be better because not printing the entire string as the only one list item.

Comment: I disagree. If 1 is the only multiplier, then so be it. The result shouldn't lose the data. Which that modification would do, as it produces an empty list.

Comment: In other words, if I were to specify a post-condition for this, it would include `''.join(lst) == s`. Similar to how `sep.join(s.split(sep))` should be `s` again. So for example  `'abc'.split('x')` needs to `['abc']`, not `[]` or some other kind of "failure" result, even though no actual split occurred.

Comment: Here a one-liner version using the walrus operator: `print(len(s)//(i:=(2*s).find(s,1))*[s[:i]])`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to deal with,

I recommend to use the built-in package: re

```
import re

test_str = "TAUXXTAUXXTAUXX"

def splitstring(string):
    match= re.match(r'(.*?)(?:\1)*$', string)
    word= match.group(1)
    return [word] * (len(string)//len(word))

splitstring(test_str)
```

output:

```
['TAUXX', 'TAUXX', 'TAUXX']
```

Comment: I don't want to initialize the target cause i don't know it the code detect it

Comment: @YussefRaoufAbdelmisih :  You don't initialize anything here. The regular expression uses a non-greedy `.*?` (indicated by `?`) search for deliberate character sequence and a greedy (all you can get) positive look ahead `(?:` using the pattern found by the non-greedy expression requiring the repeating pattern to extend until the end of the string (indicated by $). Nothing is assumed about the string content. It works more or less the same way as the solution using `find` searching for the string in its double beginning with the second character in order not to directly find itself in itself.